# Converting .ply files to .las for ArcGIS input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, import, las, ply

I'm trying to open a .ply file (point cloud in ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Pro), but I can't.

How can I convert the .ply file to .las, or open .ply in ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Do you know to accept an answer? It seems your question has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the .ply files (aka [Polygon File Format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/)) to .las with other software, and then, import it in ArcGIS.

For example:

- PDAL: supports [reading](https://pdal.io/stages/readers.ply.html#readers-ply) and [writing](https://pdal.io/stages/writers.ply.html#writers-ply) .ply files (ASCII and binary). You can convert them with the [translate](https://pdal.io/apps/translate.html) tool.
- LAStools: supports conversion of ASCII .ply files (treats it as text file) with `las2las` tool (see [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/lastools/KDClu4bS4a8/iBWQY1X6CgAJ)).
- CloudCompare: supports conversion of ASCII .ply files (see [supported file formats](https://github.com/unitycoder/UnityPointCloudViewer/wiki/Import-Formats)). Conversion can be accomplished directly from the GUI ([reference](https://github.com/unitycoder/UnityPointCloudViewer/wiki/Converting-Points-Clouds-with-CloudCompare#export-settings-for-ply-mesh)).

Comment: Thank you @Andre. How do I convert PLY ASCII files into PLY binary files in PDAL?

Comment: @Sher, see the ply writer's 'storage_mode' parameter: https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/writers.ply.html#writers-ply.

Comment: Thanks @Andre. Is following the right script? It throws no error. But not sure if it if converting into PLY binary. How can I check that?  `json = """{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.ply",
      "filename":"merged.ply"
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.ply",
      "storage_mode":"little endian",
      "filename":"merged_bin_le.ply"
    }
  ]
}"""

import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.validate() 
pipeline.execute()`

Comment: Hi @Sher, since you are trying to do a different type of conversion than OP asked, I suggest you ask a separate question about this. Tks.