# Convert .ply and .lin files to any file format readable by QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, file-formats

**My issue:**
I'm trying to open .ply and .lin files in QGIS but they do not appear to be supported, (although this might also have to do with the fact that there are actual issues with my data - see below).

**My question:**
How can I convert the .ply and .lin files to something/anything that QGIS can read?

**Here are my troubleshooting steps so far:**

First of all, here are a few descriptions of the file types:

**PLY File Format - Description 1**
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/

**PLY File Format - Description 2**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)

PLY files can be in ASCII or BINARY form. I believe mine are in ASCII form, according to the README text document that came with the datasets.

**One major place I'm running into trouble is that:**
Apparently PLY and LIN files require [a header](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/the-ply-format.html), but my data does not appear to contain headers, per both me not seeing any headers when viewing the data in [Atom](https://atom.io/) and an "unable to locate headers" error I received when trying to open the files in [MeshLab](http://www.meshlab.net/), (open source software that allows viewing and converting of PLY files).

**Similar SE Question:**
I've also seen [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314732/converting-ply-files-to-las-for-arcgis-input?rq=1) regarding converting .ply to .las, but the solution seems a bit convoluted for my purposes, and without any headers I don't think anything is going to be able to read my files at this point anyway.

**Next steps / new question:**
When I view the files in Atom, I can see all of the attributes. I can actually add the headers listed in the README text doc, adding them to the PLY and LIN files in Atom, and then I can save them out as CSVs, which I can then open and view in Excel. What I see in the PLY file is all of the attributes of each feature. What I see in the LIN file is all of the geometry (lat/longs). Both files do have unique IDs that can be used to join up both of these files.

However, since these are polygons, and not points, it's not an easy enough join with each record having only 1 pair of lat/longs. Some records have a handful of lat/long pairs, and some have over a dozen. In many cases one feature has multiple rows of lat/long pairs, which I'm interpreting as multi-part features.

So I have all of these data, but I can't figure out a way to manually convert these CSVs into some kind of spatial format. The problem is I have all of the data I need, I just don't know how to make it spatial.

**Snapshot of PLY csv:**
[image]

**Snapshot of LIN csv:**
[image]

Comment: what .ply and .lin file are supposed to be ? where did they come from ? without more detail it's hard to answer

Comment: @J.R I added clarification to the question. Also, why has it been closed? I see a ton of questions like these on here. What is the point of this forum then? I cannot give any more details about the work as it's confidential. I think it's a simple question - how to convert one geospatial format to another... what is the problem?

Comment: @J.R How is this question any different from this question, which received a helpful answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314732/converting-ply-files-to-las-for-arcgis-input?rq=1

Comment: I asked for clarification because some extension could refer to several different thing (some software will use custom extension on what is in fact simple txt or xml file while the same extension could be used by different proprietary format from different software) so knowing witch software output these file or at least what should be inside really help to give meaningful answer.

Comment: That being said your question is totally legitimate and a question could be reopened (and often is) after clarification and this one will probably be reopened soon (I voted to close before your edit). As a side note you should update your question with the one you refer in your second comment and explain why it didn't help you (if yours is not any different it risk to be closed again as duplicate...;-))

Comment: @J.R Great. Thanks for that clarification. I was assuming closed was more of a permanent thing. But now I realize it's not. I'll update it with the link from the comments, too. Thank you!

Comment: Does you ply store mash or point cloud? QGIS can handle mesh data but not ply format. If it is a mesh try to convert it to one of the supported formats (see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html). If it is a point cloud convert it to ascii format and load as delimited text file (for huge point clouds it is probably not optimal).

Comment: @Zoltan You know, I have no idea. I'm guessing it is *not* a point cloud though. That just wouldn't make sense to me given the type of features it contains. Assuming it is mesh, how would you convert the .ply to one of those supported formats? (I'm assuming you're referring to NetCDF, GRIB, XMDF, DAT, and 3Di, as per listed at that link you shared). If it somehow turns out to be a point cloud, how would you convert it to ascii?

Comment: @Zoltan - checking this out now... https://codeyarns.com/2011/08/20/convert-between-ascii-and-binary-ply-file-formats/

Comment: @Zoltan - well, actually *this* is the tool: http://www.meshlab.net/

Comment: I was able to view these files in Atom (https://atom.io/). But it does not appear that there is any PLY header information, which is probably why I'm getting a "cannot find headers" error in MeshLab... I've also learned that the LIN file is what holds the geometry. So now that I can see the contents of the PLY and LIN files (and there's a text doc with the field names), I may be able to create a CSV by joining them up based on the unique IDs and then converting that to something...

Comment: I've updated this question with lots of additional information now about where I'm at in this process.

Comment: Created a spin-off question about the CSVs here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362281/create-polygons-from-coordinate-pairs-in-csv-where-total-number-of-pairs-varies